# add content only when page injection into the dom is ready vía callback

Tags: javascript, events, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm developing an app using JQM + Phonegap.

In order to avoid device slowdown and crash application, I'm using the JQM single page navigation model because it allows auto DOM size management.

I'm dynamically injecting pages using href="page.html" into the DOM as the user navigates and manually using changePage('page.html') to handle user interactions.

So, as far as I'm conerned, on those pages that use server-data I need to:

1. Load (inject) new page into the DOM to access target divs/containers
2. dynamically place new data (append)

Please, take a look into this example for illustrative purposes:

```
 function loadData (myJSONObject){

    // inject page
    $.mobile.changePage('page2.html');

    //load data
    for(var i=0; i<myJSONObject.data.length;i++){
    name = myJSONObject.data[i].name;
    link = myJSONObject.data[i].description;

    // #listData is the target container from page2.html                    
    $("<a />",{
        text: name,
        href: link
        }).appendTo(                                                
            $("<li />",{
            id: name,
            }).appendTo('#listData'));
    }
```

This code results in an empty list because the JQM page injection function(s) takes longer than loading data due to javascript asynchronous behaviour

**Note that:

- using multipage model and changePage('#target') works
- testing with setTimeOut() and forcing the data loading loop to wait also works but I assume that is not optimal neither a good developing practise

QUESTION: Is there a callback or way to start loading data only when new page is fully injected into the DOM so does target container availability?

Comment: See the events section of the documentation: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html. Not having found this page on your own, I would suggest perusing the documentation in general.

Answer (score 0):

There are several pageLoad events that fire at different stages of transitioning from one page to the next. It's all very well documented here: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html

I believe in your case the event you are after is the `pageinit` event.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed I'm developing a complex app connected to a webservice. It's the mobile version of a webapp.

I'm emulating a MVC model so each page has it's own controller.js, model.js, view.js and a html5 page (single-page documents). That's why I'm injecting pages into the DOM using changePage('page2.html'), letting the JQM framework take care of the DOM, back button functionallity, transitions...

As the user navigates pages are shown, hidden or injected deppending on if new data is required or it's just about showing a page from the DOM (hidden->shown) with last data and a "refresh" button or scroll-down load-new-data functionality.

Please, have a look on this example:

Imagine an app to discover new restaurants with 3 pages. Home (show latest news from restaurants you suscribe), Restaurant (List of all restaurants available) and RestaurantProfile (info and suscribe/unsuscribe button).

So, when a user click on a restaurant from the list I need to take data from the server and placing into the different target wrappers from RestaurantProfile.html but first of all this page has to be injected into the DOM because it's not possible to load data into an isolate page and then inject it into the DOM. That's not possible.

I don't know even care about if that page is already into the DOM or has been removed. That's up to JQM framework (changePage() executes loadPage() before if required). I only need to know which page is demanded and pass the corresponding data. That's all.

Now, increase this complexity much more adding users, users profiles, users feed and comments... It can easy become a 10 page app.

That's why I decided to have single-page documents, to maintain a "clean" app structure so it's easy to add new functionality in the future.

pageinit event - It must be placed into the corresponding page and will trigger a function allways. But, as I said before, sometimes it's a simple navigation situation (up to JQM navBar) and sometimes I manage the petition and this is when I require to add data form server.

Handicap. How to know in which situation we are?

$.mobile.changePage('to', options) function - Let's figure it out if my problem can be solved by both using this function and the pageload event (I couldn't find in the domumentation if you can use same options argument for pageinit event)...

reloadPage > Can be setted to true when new data is required despite I don't know what else JQM framework is going to do even what does it means in terms of functionality...

data > I really need to able to set this into a json object. But I haven't make this work yet...

I hope the problem I'm addressing is much clear now.

QUESTIONS :

1) Does pageinit event handle same 'options' argument than 
pageload event?

2) How set 'options > data' argument into a json object and correctly access its content on pageload event?

3) What does the reloadPage = true exactly entail?